# Background color does not show in style.css but does in index.html

Tags: html, css

New to HTML5 & CSS.
Using Sublime Text 3
currently following a video to create a one page portfolio.
video link provided: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMupINi7fWQ
In the video Abdul Khan is putting CSS background color code in the style.css panel/folder.
Example:

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {}

        #container {}
            header {
                background: #ADD8E6;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }

    #one{ 
    }
```

But when I try and put this code in my style.css, it does not work.

The background color only works when I am in the index.html and place the "bgcolor" within the body.

body bgcolor="#ADD8E6"

I was hoping someone could explain to me why I can't get it to work in style.css, but can in index.html

Thanks!

Comment: Have you include your css file in index.html ?
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your code in head section of index.html
Like this:

```
<head>
<style>
header {
        background: #ADD8E6;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

if it work then let me know.
And then you just have to check the linking of CSS file on your index.html page.

Because you have not link your CSS properly.

Comment: No. I have made several attempts and nothing that I tried works. I had followed the video tutorial step by step.

Comment: The following works 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 header {
  background: #ADD8E6;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
 }
</style>
 <meta charset= "utf-8">
 <title>HTML Portfolio Resume by Charles Walters</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="" = "container">
  <header>This Sucks</header>
  <section id= "one"></section>
 </div>
</body>
</html><html>
<head>
 <meta charset= "utf-8">
 <title>HTML Portfolio Resume by Charles Walters</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: This works too.<html>
<head>
 <meta charset= "utf-8">
 <title>HTML Portfolio Resume by Charles Walters</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
 <div id="" = "container">
  <header>This Sucks</header>
  <section id= "one"></section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This does not work.

}
body {}
 #container {}
  header {
   background: #ADD8E6;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
  }
  #one{}

Answer (score -3):

Try this snippet in your style.css to set the background color of the body tag:

```css
body {
    background-color: ##AABBCC;
}
```

[W3Schools - background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

Comment: First: wrong syntax. Second: w3schools have worst docs, mdn are much  better.

Comment: I have tried body {
    background-color: ##AABBCC;
}